# Why run Visual Studio as "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

What is the difference between using Visual Studio 2012 "Run as Administrator" mode and otherwise? Why do developers prefer using VS in administrator mode? What are the advantages/privileges that one gets?
I may be naive enough to ask this one but I am just curious. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that I ever needed administrator privileges in VS for would be the Azure simulator, but [Stijn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261828/73070) lists a lot more things. But few of these are typical, depending on what you do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [MSDN: User Permissions and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj662724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You can do nearly everything in the Visual Studio IDE as a normal
>   user, but, you need administrator permissions to complete the
>   following tasks:
>
> - [Installing Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e2h7fzkw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Upgrading from a trial edition of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg442061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - Installing, updating, or removing local Help content.
> - [Developing solutions for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231582%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Acquiring a developer license for Windows Store](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241313).
> - [Adding classic COM controls to the Toolbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165354%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Installing and using add-ins that were written by using classic COM in the IDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5abkeks7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Using post-build events that register a component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e85wte0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Including a registration step when you build C++ projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e85wte0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Debugging applications that run with elevated permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d0b8xh0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Debugging applications that a run under a different user account, such as ASP.NET websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w2faa92k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Debugging in Zone for XAML Browser Applications (XBAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Using the emulator to debug cloud service projects for Windows Azure](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=266725).
> - [Configuring a firewall for remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Profiling an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - [Deploying a web application to Internet Information Services (IIS) on a local computer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=266478).
> - [Changing how you participate in the Visual Studio Customer Experience Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zzszcehe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I took the liberty of migrating the links too.

Comment: @aritra I wouldn't know, I have UAC disabled and don't need to do most of these tasks, but I assume the list is correct. If you find it isn't, please let us know :)

Comment: @Stijn Yes I am also not aware if all these tasks require VS to run on admin mode, its just that i was curious abt this one "Adding classic COM controls to the Toolbox."

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista introduced User Account Control which means that you are running all programs as a standard user even if you are an admin. There are certain things that you in VS that requires you to be running as an admin, not a standard user. For example running Windows Azure emulators, asp.net dev server, etc.

You can run VS as a standard user but sooner or later you will run into issues.